# How do I send a Skype message to multiple contacts in a list from a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, skype4com

I would like to know how to send a Skype message to multiple contacts at a time. For example, the textbox contains this:

> 1. user1
> 2. user2
> 3. user3

Right now, to send a message to a specific contact I use:

```
Skypattach.SendMessage("username", "message")
```

So instead of having to do

```
Skypattach.SendMessage("username1", "message")
Skypattach.SendMessage("username2", "message")
Skypattach.SendMessage("username3", "message")
```

I would like it to be quicker, to grab the usernames from a textbox.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is that example exactly what the text in your textbox looks like? If so use the Textboxes Lines collection, iterate through that splitting on the space to extract the username.

Comment: @MarkHall Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flesh out my comment, the TextBox control has a [Lines Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) which you can iterate through to get each individual line. So if your text looks exactly like what your question shows, you can use something like this. Notice that I am splitting on the period, you can use the space or what ever delineator you decide on.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SendSkype(TextBox1.Lines)
End Sub

Private Sub SendSkype(rawUserNameData As String())
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim receipients() As String
    If rawUserNameData.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim receipients(rawUserNameData.Count - 1)
        For x = 0 To rawUserNameData.Count - 1
            Try

                receipients(x) = Trim(Split(rawUserNameData(x), ".")(1))

            Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException 'Catch Unproperly formatted entries
            End Try
        Next
        For Each s As String In receipients
            Skypattach.SendMessage(s, "Message")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks for your time, have a nice day.